# Expressing an arbitrary natural number as the difference of squarefree ones

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Is it true that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x, y \in \mathbb{N}: x,y$ are squarefree, & $n = x-y$?

---

I think so, but I am not sure that I am quite proving it. Here is my line of thought:
Let $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ be the set of squarefree natural numbers. Represent upper density by $D$. Then we know that $D(S) = \frac{6}{\pi^2} > 0$. There is a proposition that says that, since $S$ has positive upper density, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}: D(S \cap (S-n)) > 0$ too. Then $\exists x,y \in S: y = x-n$. Therefore $\exists x,y \in S: n = x-y$.

So, I think that I have proven existence of at least one such $n$, but I am not sure that I have universality. The statement is supposed to hold *for all* $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I am looking for more combinatorial methods of proof, but it is a duplicate question.